# Can i get excel spreadsheet of the details of data sets under an organization through CKAN?

Tags: ckan

Currently involved in managing a data portal using CKAN. Was wondering if there was a way to create a spreadsheet of details (such as names, date published, etc) of the datasets published by an organization.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is to use the facet package_search by organization name e.g  https://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_search?fq=organization:ckanr_test_org. This will return all of the datasets that belong to an organization: org_name, that you can parse to an excel file or get as JSON. Note that if you don't provide authorization you will get information for only public datasets that belong to the organization. Check the API documentation I think there could be additional API calls to get more info.